# What does the error code estimated adjustment 'w' is infinite mean for bootES

Tags: r, function, plyr, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to bootstrap my data using the bootES function in R.

SGdistance_data is my original data frame with each row being a different sample and Species, DistanceZone, TimeFrame, and Avg_PercentCover(my response variable) as different columns.

I am trying to determine the effect size of a disturbance event on seagrass percent cover. My samples are subdivided into Species, DistanceZone, and TimeFrame (pre-Breach which is my control, and post-Breach which is my treatment, the contrast that I am trying to estimate effect sizes for). When I run the following code I get the error code:

Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,  : 
  estimated adjustment 'w' is infinite
Called from: bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o, 
    h = h, hdot = hdot, hinv = hinv, ...)

```
BCA.1<-plyr::ddply(SGdistance_data, c("Species", "DistanceZone"),          
function(df) {
summary(bootES(SGdistance_data,effect.type="unstandardized", R=2000,   
data.col="Avg_PercentCover", group.col= "TimeFrame",contrast = c("post-
Breach"=1, "pre-Breach"=-1), ci.type = c("bca")))
})
```

not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. I have been able to run the bootES on my original data frame without subselecting for DistanceZone or Species but not sure hwy it does not work with my function